# Populating listview with FirebaseListAdapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using counter value for counting my `ListView` items. But when I am scrolling down and back scrolling up it still count value inside of my code and changes values.

This values should 1 and 2 instead of 7 and 8...

[image: should be 1 and 2]

Here is my code

```
 DatabaseReference myQuery = databaseReference.child("Tests").child(PIN).child("Questions");
    FirebaseListAdapter<QuizStatistic_list> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<QuizStatistic_list>(this, QuizStatistic_list.class, R.layout.list_quiz_statistic, myQuery) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, QuizStatistic_list model, int position) {

            TextView quizQuestion, questionNumber, ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD;


            quizQuestion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_quizQuestion);
            questionNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_questionNumber);
            ansA = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_ansA);
            ansB = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_ansB);
            ansC = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_ansC);
            ansD = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_ansD);


            quizQuestion.setText(model.getQuestion());
            questionNumber.setText(counter.toString());
            ansA.setText("A:  " + model.getAnswerA());
            ansB.setText("B:  " + model.getAnswerB());
            ansC.setText("C:  " + model.getAnswerC());
            ansD.setText("D:  " + model.getAnswerD());

           //This value counts listview items
           counter++;
        }
    };
    questionsList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: `This value counts listview items` -- I don't think that is true. It increments every time data *enters Firebase* and *views are recycled*, which is always `>=` the data actually in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use position instead of counter.!

```
questionNumber.setText(""+position+1);
```

position is index number of your array list .!
so it will start from 0 by adding one it will show your desired result first number will be index 0+1=1;
maybe it will help u like

Comment: I solved problem by writing my **questionNumber** inside of my Firebase Database and then populating it in my **ListView**. Now it is something like that: `questionNumber.setText(model.getQuestionNumber())`